# How to create entity with a collection-type field in JHipster?

Tags: jhipster

In our project, we work with a domain model *Document*. A *document* may have several *titles*, so with my JPA knowledge I'd model the *Document* entity like so:

```
@Entity
public class Document {

    private Set<String> titles;

    // ... getters and setters
}
```

How can I have jHipster generate entities with collection attributes (or, synomymously, collection fields)?

Answer (score 3):

Depending on jdl document [here](https://jhipster.github.io/jdl/#annexes) the collection type for field is not handled yet.

I guess you already think of creating an title object and create one-to-many relation with document right?

Comment: Yes, I thought about solving my challenge by just introducing a *Title* entity and setting up a one-to-many relationship between *Document* and *Title*. But it feels like a workaround, as *Title* is more of a [value object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_object) rather than a full-fledged entity.

Comment: Yes your right it is a workaround, for that you can modify jdl generator to handle collection fields. It is not a big deal I think.